# Recommendations for Introduction to Quantum Flavourdynamics

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, resource-recommendations

It's surprisingly hard to find any resources on this on the internet. I'd want a suitable for self-study introduction to the QFD for someone with only a basic understanding of Quantum Field Theory. While it's not a requirement, it would be good if it was freely available online.

Comment: Yes, it is true, even after two decades and some the world wide web can not quite compete with a well kept scientific library. I guess this would warrant a physical visit to one of those ancient, long forgotten places with the slightly musty smell? ;-)

Comment: I don't have any scientific libraries near where I live, though.

Comment: That is a serious problem. I mean it, that is a serious problem because the most valuable resources are not online and there are no signs that they will come online. Your best bet is a literature search and whatever free papers you can scrounge on arxiv and from the few journals that are available for free.

Comment: @Qwedfsf How about "Gauge Theory of Weak Interactions" by Greiner? I think that it is pretty much entry-level. There is also "Gauge Theories of the Strong and Electroweak Interaction" by Böhm, Denner and Joos, which is a very good book, but starting on a slightly higher level.